# Is it possible to choose only specific discord users to show user context menu interactions on via discord py interactions?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am working in discord-py-interactions. I want to limit what users show certain context menu interactions when they are clicked on. For example, I want to only show most commands on the bot when it is clicked on.

```
@user_context_menu(name="get_id", scopes=[1095478300228472982])
async def repeat(ctx: interactions.ContextMenuContext):
    member: interactions.Member = ctx.target
    await ctx.send(member.id)
```

This code gives me an error because that `scopes` parameter is meant for guild ids, not user ids. Is this doable another way though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot. The [`commands.CommandTree.context_menu`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.app_commands.CommandTree.context_menu) documentation does not support any parameter to apply this context menu for specific users only.